# How to get adjacency matrix of each detected cluster in R?

Tags: r, graph, adjacency-matrix

Is there a simple way to convert each cluster detected by an k-means to an adjacency matrix in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could bind the clusters to the data.

```
res <- kmeans(as.matrix(iris[1:2]), 2)
cbind(res$cluster, iris[1:2])
```

To split the matrix into separate clusters

```
split(cbind(res$cluster, iris[1:2]), res$cluster)
```

Comment: i want that each of the two cluster is given as an adjacency matrix. if for example cluster 1, contains nodes a, b, c,d and cluster  2, contains nodes f, u,y,k and l. it have to give two afjacency matrix one of size 4 for the cluster 1 and the second adjacency matrix is of size 5.i want to know if there is a simple way to get this in R

Comment: great! glad to hear it